# Using CrossWalk for making a Call using WebRTC

Tags: android, webview, webrtc, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

The call is working perfectly fine for the first time.

But after that it freezes just before connecting to WebRTC, this is currently happening only on Samsung Galaxy S5 out of my 5 devices that I test upon.

Other devices are:

- Motorola Moto G2
- Nexus 5X
- Samsung Grand
- Samsung S2 (Genymotion emulator)

Please point me to something that can help... Sorry, but I don't have the logs for this error

Answer (score 0):

I am from Crosswalk team. We are maintaining some basic tests for WebRTC on Crosswalk and haven't find similar issues.
If you can share your test page, it could accelerate the problem fixing.
Another way is to file bugs a bug JIRA where we use to track bugs,

https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow.  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a
Q&A site, where we reserve the answer space for answers. Please check out our
short [tour].  This "answer" is more appropriate as a "comment" in the Question.